# How do you compile PJSip iPhone for both Device & Simulator to work with siphon on iOS 3 & iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sip, pjsip

I am attempting to compile and run [pjsip](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) and [siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) for iOS 3 and iOS 4.

I am following the instructions via pjsip.org site on "Getting Started" for iPhone.

I am also following the instructions on siphon's site.

My goal is to get siphon's application working on my device and simulator for both iOS 3 and iOS4, but just getting past the compilation stage of pjsip has been a headache.

So I decided to just compile for the device, and at least get siphon up and running, but that seems to be more of a headache.

The compilation instructions are not clear (at least not to me as a beginner) and moreover, there are two sets of compilation instructions: 1) a read me inside the source code, and 2) on the wiki page of the site.

My questions are as such:

1. What are the step by step instructions on getting pjsip & siphon to
   compile and run on both Device & Simultaor for iOS 3 and 4.  (I am
   aware of the lipo command, but I'm not clear how to use it,
   considering there are many many files, and too much opportunity to
   make mistakes)
2. Should I be working with pjsip version 1.x or version 2.x ?
3. Is siphon up-to-date?
4. Within the siphon source directory, there is a siphon2 and siphon4
       directory ... yet only within the siphon2 directory is there an
       .xcodeproj.   How do implement the siphon4 project files?

Answer (score 0):

The Siphon2 on code.google.com does not work on iOS 4.

This one does:
https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles